# Illegal Character when trying to compile java : error 187 191

Tags: java, compilation

I'm trying to compile java to class and I'm getting error, this is the some first lines

```
    /*      */ package gcb;
    /*      */ import gcb.bot.ChatThread;
    /*      */ import gcb.bot.SQLThread;
    /*      */ import gcb.plugin.PluginManager;
    /*      */ import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    /*      */ import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    /*      */ import java.net.InetAddress;
    /*      */ import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    /*      */ import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Im getting error like this, please someone help me. Can anyone solve this problem remotely? Please i need to solve this problem ASAP

```
 C:\project>javac GChatbot.java
    GChatbot.java:1: error: illegal character: \187
    ∩╗┐/*      */ package gcb;
     ^
    GChatbot.java:1: error: illegal character: \191
    ∩╗┐/*      */ package gcb;
      ^
    2 errors
```

Please help me

Comment: What editor are you using? Never use Word to program.

Comment: What you have posted does not contain any of the characters in the error message: give a link to the actual file or provide more details on how you saved the source code file.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/Q6KZV03u/GChatBot.html? there is the link of java file, someone please just compile it to class

Answer (score 6):

Save your file without [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Im tried to save without BOM, but when i save without BOM there is more 100 errors :))

Comment: @Erkhemee Enkhtaivan: what errors do you get now? I cant download your file because I do not want to sign up there. Can't you reduce your problem to a code snippet you can show us here?

Comment: could you give me your ID? I'll go pv please

Comment: No, certainly not. If you want help, post your problem here.

Comment: 4shared.com/file/Q6KZV03u/GChatBot.html? i cant post here entire java, there are about 2000 lines

Comment: maybe you should contact the original author of those 2000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the source file as ANSI will solve this problem. It did for me. The source file can be created using Notepad and saved as xx.java in the ANSI format.
Best Wishes

Answer (score 0):

What Xie says is the correct answer, since the error is in the first line, where byte order mark is located.

What I had to do was to save the file as ANSI. But after this several errors appear because ANSI codification does not include several characters of foreign languages, therefore I had to manually correct inside the IDE the special characters that were all over my comments and documentation. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Save your file as ANSI (encoding). Thus you can get correct